# AngularJS: Nested http call doesn't update the view

Tags: angularjs, typescript

In a particular scenario, I need to call the the github api to retrieve a specific user's info. Then issue a second call to retrieve the user's repositories:

```
search(login: string): void {
       this.user = undefined; 
       // first call               
       this.githubApi.getUser(login)
            .then(user => {
                this.user = user;
                // second call
                this.githubApi.getRepos(user.repos_url)
                    .then(reposResponse => {
                        this.repos = reposResponse.repos;
                        // I don't like to call this.$scope.$apply() !!;
                    });
            });
    }
```

The first call gets executed and the bound elements to `this.user` gets updated with no problem in the view.
The second call gets executed and the result is returned successfully and `this.repos` is set correctly. But, the bound elements on the view are not updated.

If I call `this.$scope.$apply()` in the very last line of the second callback, it makes the view update work but I guess this is not correct approach.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know , why Angular-Js is not updating the view.

You have used `$scope.$apply()`, so I'm assuming you already know , how it works and why we use it. Now , to the problem!

Sometimes when you make a callback - `nested callback` in particular - Angular does not update the view. Sometimes angular thinks that it does not need to update the view because of callbacks. And the watchers do not take action when the value changes of the variable that they are watching.

Then you use `$scope.$apply()` to run the digest cycle again (assuming you already know the digest cycle if you don't then let me know). And it makes the watchers to update the view.In your case, digest cycle is not running, that is why angular is not updating the view. If your digest cycle was running , angular would have given you error. So, it will tell angular to run digest cycle again because two-way binding is not working properly.

I don't think there is another way. But if there is a way, I would love to know that way. Also its not a bad approach. It was made for these kind of problems.

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes, I am familiar with `digest cycle`. What even surprises me is that chaining `then` is still not working!

Comment: `.then() chaining` is also a callback in which we are returning promise, because JavaScript is `asynchronous`. So, it will not wait and will `execute` the remaining code. Its a callback and i think angular did not update its `watchers`. and the `response life` is not in angular js `digest cycle`. So, Angular don't know about it. We need to tell him, You have missed something, run your digest cycle again and include what you have missed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are not willing to use `$scope.apply();`, try updating your `getRepos` service response code with:

```
setTimeout(
 () => {
  this.repos = reposResponse.repos;
 }, 0
)
```

Comment: I have doubts, @hamzox will this work? because with `0 time` it will run right after `angular digest cycle`.  I think, you need to use `$scope.$apply()` in `setTimeout`  to `update` the vaules.